# Disaster recovery (multi data center deployments) in JBoss Fuse ESB 6.2

Tags: jbossfuse

We are migrating from old Fuse Source ESB to JBoss Fuse ESB 6.2 version, so we look for better deployment strategies using the newer version of JBoss Fuse ESB 6.2 with Disaster recovery (multi data center deployments) & with in same data center - a Master/Slave (Primary/Secondary) nodes with automatic fail over options.How to achieve this in newer version?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, I believe Fuse Fabric will work well.    You can read more here
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Getting_Started/files/Deploy-Scalable.html

Answer (score 0):

What is the question exactly? What is your architecture?
DR for what, Fabric, A-MQ, Camel containers...
I've blogged on the topic [here](http://www.ofbizian.com/2015/07/jboss-fuse-deployment-considerations.html) that might be a good start.